# conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Tags: visual-c++, com, variant

On migrating a VC++ 6.0 developed code to Visual studio 2008, I got the below warnings

> > warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Code Snippet:

```
STDMETHODIMP CTextFileParser::FormatString(
     long lTargetType, BSTR szFormat, BSTR szInput, VARIANT *value)
{
   //blahblahblah
   CComVariant vErg(szSource.c_str()); // Definition of vErg
   vErg.vt = lTargetType; // <<<< C4244
```

> > warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'long' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data

Code Snippet:

```
STDMETHODIMP CField::get_ContentWithType(long lType, VARIANT *pVal)
{
   HRESULT hRC;
   CComVariant oNewValue(m_content);           // Definition of oNewValue
   hRC = oNewValue.ChangeType(lType, NULL);    // <<<< C4244
   if (SUCCEEDED(hRC)) oNewValue.Detach(pVal);
   return hRC;
}
```

I'm unable to fix this warning?..

Comment: The first code snippet seems very fishy. Why set a variant from a string and then change its `vt` without changing its actual contents type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VARTYPE` is 16 bits.

```
typedef unsigned short VARTYPE;
```

In order to kill the warning, you should use old style C cast or preferably C++ `static_cast`.

```
vErg.vt = static_cast<VARTYPE>( lTargetType );
```

If you can, a better, but more complex, solution would be to refactor your code, passing `VARTYPE` arguments instead of `long` ones.

Comment: @user3360310 be sure to always pass arguments fitting in 16 bits :-)